# Weka illegal options : -C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 2 -M -V -1 -W 1

Tags: java, model, command, svm, weka

when using the following command line
`java -classpath ./weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.SMO  -C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 2 -M -V -1 -W 1 
-K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.StringKernel -P 0 -C 250007 -IC 200003 -L 0.5 -ssl 4 -ssl-max 9" -l BCPred14.model -T Examples/data/BCPred20.nr80.arff > out.txt` .

I get the following error : `Weka exception: Illegal options: -C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 2 -M -V -1 -W 1 -K weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.StringKernel -P 0 -C 250007 -IC 200003 -L 0.5 -ssl 4 -ssl-max 9`

When i remove all options the command executes, but using any option i get the same error. All the options chosen are documented from weka so i don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I notice that the quotes after "-K" are missing in the error message and the message itself only includes your options up to the second quotes. Did you by any chance use the wrong quotes (non-ASCII ones)?

Comment: I have tried changing the quotes, but even when i completely remove the kernel options and only leave the classifier ones, it still doesn't work so that probably isn't the issue here.

Comment: Are you using the correct Weka version? I just tried your command line with Weka 3.8.1 and it works just fine.

Comment: I did try it on the latest version aswell, but the error appears to be the same. In what OS did you try it in?

Comment: I tried it on Windows 10 with Oracle Java 8 (I think)

Comment: How exactly did you test the command without the files needed e.g. the model file and the input ".arff" file?

Comment: I just used one of the .arff files that included in the Weka installation.

Comment: Did you use the command without a model or else which model did you use?

Comment: I first trained model and stored it to a model file, then I used your command (with adapted file names). Does the problem also persist with other classifiers or just with SMO?